# SubList test cases

Tags: java, testing, junit, sublist

Im testing methods of SubList(Java.util.List) native implementation. Im using Java 8 api documentation. For toArray() method, I have only 3 tests. Can u help me to come up with more test cases? Thanks

```
@Test
public void toArrayBasicSub() {
    fillList();
    List<String> expectedList = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5");
    String[] expected = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    List<String> sub = list.subList(0, 5);
    Object[] actual = sub.toArray();
    assertEquals(expectedList,list);
    assertArrayEquals(expected,actual);
}

@Test
public void toArrayEmpty() {
    String[] expected = {};
    List<String> sub = list.subList(0, 0);
    Object[] actual = sub.toArray();
    assertArrayEquals(expected,actual);
}

@Test
public void toArrayNull() {
    fillList();
    List<String> expected = null;
    List<String> sub = list.subList(0, 5);
    sub = null;

    boolean thrownException = false;
    try {
        sub.toArray();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        thrownException = true;
    }
    assertTrue(thrownException);
}
```

Comment: Why are you testing the JDK's methods?  This is already tested by the team who develops it.  You should test your own code.

Comment: And don't use try-catch to test exceptions. Either use `@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)` or the ExpectedException test rule.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are targeting List.subList() for learning purposes only (as there are no other good reasons to test JDK methods!).

So, you are basically looking for feedback ... so lets help with that.

First thing: be **clear** about the **scope** you are testing. You say you want to test **subList()**. If so, then your tests should **only** be about sublist.

And then, the number of reasonable tests is really short:

1. Test the result for calling subList on an **empty** list
2. Test the result for calling subList on an non-empty list (simple case: with one element to show up in subList)
3. Test the result for calling subList on an non-empty list (complex case: with several elements to show up in subList)

You don't need much else. Specifically: when your job is to test the **subList()** call; then you don't need any test case for **toArray**.

subList() is called on a List, and returns a List. That is the only thing that matters here. What one does afterwards, to a list created by a call to subList() ... is not in the scope of testing subList()!